# @Id for oracle.rowid

Tags: orm, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

Howto declare @Entity class for oracle table w/o PK?

I has received the error message:
Column "rowid" cannot be resolved on table "LOG"

when doing mapping like this:

@Entity
public class Log implements Serializable {
...
@Id
private ROWID rowid;
...
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Howto declare @Entity class for oracle table w/o PK?

Mapping a ROWID as `Id` isn't supported by standard JPA and I couldn't find any obvious proof that EclipseLink is providing an extension for this (I only found [this message](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg00892.html)).

But this is not your only option and the JPA wikibook has a good paragraph about this situation:

> #### [No Primary Key](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#No_Primary_Key)
>
> Sometimes your object or table has no
>   primary key. The best solution in this
>   case is normally to add a generated id
>   to the object and table. If you do not
>   have this option, sometimes there is a
>   column or set of columns in the table
>   that make up a unique value. You can
>   use this unique set of columns as your
>   id in JPA. The JPA `Id` does not
>   always have to match the database
>   table primary key constraint, nor is a
>   primary key or a unique constraint
>   required.
>
> If your table truly has no unique
>   columns, then use all of the columns
>   as the id. Typically when this occurs
>   the data is read-only, so even if the
>   table allows duplicate rows with the
>   same values, the objects will be the
>   same anyway, so it does not matter
>   that JPA thinks they are the same
>   object. The issue with allowing
>   updates and deletes is that there is
>   no way to uniquely identify the
>   object's row, so all of the matching
>   rows will be updated or deleted.
>
> If your object does not have an id,
>   but its' table does, this is fine.
>   Make the object and `Embeddable`
>   object, embeddable objects do not have
>   ids. You will need a `Entity` that
>   contains this `Embeddable` to persist
>   and query it.